# Make a Glyphicon-plus slim and color not change on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, glyphicons

Is there a way to make glyphicon-plus smaller?
I tried `glyphicon-plus` but the `+` I get is thick. The code snippet is

`<a>{href: "#/agencies/new", class: 'btn btnadd pull-right'}
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>`

My style snippet is

```
.btnadd {
border: none;
color: white;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
border-radius: 50%;
position: fixed;
bottom: 5%;
right: 1%;
background: #60BBEA !important;
padding: 12px;
font-size: 20px;
```

}

Is there any way to make the plus smaller. Also the Plus icon is white in colour, but when hovered, it turns black. Any method for prevent it from changing the color?

Answer (score 0):

Replace below style

```
.btnadd {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 1%;
    background: #60BBEA !important;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.btnadd:hover{
    color: #fff;
}

.btnadd i{
    top: 5px;
}
```

Reduce the font size in .btnadd and change the color on hover

Comment: Worked in the case of hover. However, I wanted to make the 'plus' a bit slimmer. It's too thick by default. Any method on how to?

Comment: When by slimmer, I mean like fab add button

Comment: Some glyphicon is by default thick, for slick icon you need to use other icon

Comment: It worked when I made font-family as 'Material Icons'

Answer (score 0):

Use font-size to make the plus smaller or bigger. Adjsut the number for your needs.

```
.btnadd i {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Use :hover to overwrite the default hover behaviour.

```
.btnadd i:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: No, I wanted the icon to be of same size, but to be slimmer, like that of fab icons

Comment: You can try font-weight: 100; but if the icon was just drawn in that width there is nothing you can change about it.

Comment: Worked when I changed my font-family to "Material Icons"

Answer (score 0):

To make the plus icon thin try adding the following CSS styling to the `glyphicon-plus`

```
.glyphicon-plus {
     font-family: none !important;
}
```

As for preventing the colour of the tick changing when hovering you could just set the `:hover` of the element to be the same? So essentially when hovering over the element it won't look like it's changed.

```
.btnadd:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```